# WSO2 ESB access context property in the response sequence of an HTTP endpoint

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm calling an HTTP endpoint and getting the response in 
a sequence. Response is getting logged in the `seq_sla_resp`.

```
<send receive="seq_sla_resp">
    <endpoint key="gov:EDI/SLA/endpoints/edi_sla_payment_ep.xml" />
</send>
```

Inside this response sequence I'm unable to get a property which I set previously during the call (in the main proxy).

```
<property expression="//m1:sla_row/m1:tran_id/text()"
                            name="tran_id" scope="default" type="STRING"
                            xmlns:m1="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" />
```

When I try to log the property in the `seq_sla_resp` it ends up in the below error message

```
<log>
    <property expression="$tran_id" name="tran_id" xmlns:m0="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
</log>
```

Following is the error.

```
SynapseXPath Evaluation of the XPath expression $tran_id resulted in an error
org.jaxen.UnresolvableException: Variable tran_id
```

How can i get the context value in the response sequence.

In the documentaion it says default scope has the largest life span for the property.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would find that your expression would also not work in the inSequence. You should either use `expression="$ctx:tran_id"` or `expression="get-property('tran_id')"`

Answer (score 1):

Please note that WSO2 recommends using $ctx instead of the get-property if the scope is default. The get-property methods search in the registry if the value is not available in the message context. Therefore, it affects the performance.

In your case , you can use

```
<property expression="$ctx:tran_id" name="tran_id"  scope="default" xmlns:m0="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
```

Thanks
Kranthi